# Проблема с загрузкой с флэшки

Tags: debian

Решил я поставить себе на ноут **debian**, но, так как CD/DVD привод у меня не работает, решил создать загрузочную флэшку. Образ скачал [здесь](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.5.0/i386/bt-dvd/) и записал его при помощи [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Не знаю, почему, но ноут упорно не хочет загружаться с флэшки и продолжает грузиться с жёсткого. При загрузке система флэшку видит, в BIOS установлена загрузка с флэш, gparted уверяет, что флаг boot на ней стоит, но результат один.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ноут современный? Если да, то скорее всего ищется EFI загрузчик. Нужно покопать в настройках "BIOS" - искать пункт который отвечает за типы допускаемых загрузчиков. Как точно он называется не скажу, так  как вашей версии загрузочной прошивки не знаю, но там может быть установлено что-то похожее на "Only EFI".Вообще говоря, Debian умеет и EFI загрузчик ставить, но для этого надо флешку разбивать по особому, должен быть отдельный раздел под EFI.

Comment: Загрузился через GRUB -_-